# Compile (or download binary) XMR-STAK-CPU for armv8

Tags: cpu-mining

I rented - as an experiment - a dedicated ARMv8 server. I trying to compile xmr-stak-cpu. I am running into the same issues as mentioned in:
https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu/issues/102.

Is there a working XMR miner on ARMv8 currently?

BR, Rene

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, at least I managed to build XMR-STAK-CPU for Apple mobile CPUs, which are ARMv8. Though SSE instructions have to emulated with NEON instructions, it works pretty performant.
Some details on the experiment are [here](https://kazakov.life/2017/11/01/cryptocurrency-mining-on-ios-devices/).

Answer (score 1):

XMR-stak needs SSE instructions, but there is a working ARM implementation in monero-core. You can mine directly with a full node if you don't mind the performance penalty.

Comment: Actually I am using now: https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu.git

Comment: Sorry - https://github.com/hyc/wolf-xmr-miner/tree/armv8.

Answer (score 1):

I setup a multiarch docker build for x86 arm64 and arm (wip). I can confirm it works on a number of my arm64 systems.

https://hub.docker.com/r/forcedinductionz/multiarch-cpu-miner/

Comment: cortex a53 x 8 ~ 25 h/s 1 hour average

Comment: cortex a72 x 16 - 60 h/s 1 hour average